# Need to write a java program that prints all the even numbers up from 0 through and including 100

Tags: java

I need to use if and for statements to accomplish this, and the % operator but I am not sure how to go about it.

```
    for (int v = 0; v <= 100;) {
        if (v % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(" " + v);
            v = v + 1;
        }
    }
```

This is what I have so far and it keeps printing infinite 0's.

Comment: Aren't you missing something in the for statement?...(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: If you indented your code properly, mistakes would stand out more.

Comment: you should also keep in mind , that `for(int v=0;i<=100;i+=2)System.out.println(" "+v);` would be the proper way to do so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To print the even numbers :

```
for (int v=0; v<=100; v=v+2){
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

People often think that you can only increment by one, but it's not.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem!!

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that while you remembered to increment `v`, you incremented it inside the `if` statement. Move it outside so `v` always increments and your code should work.

```
for (int v = 0; v <= 100;){
        if (v % 2 == 0){
           System.out.println(" " + v);
           v = v + 1; // <-- this is the wrong place to increment.
        }
}
```

Either move `v = v+1` just outside that next closing brace, or change it to `v++` in the third part of the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `v++` into for loop like this :

```
   for (int v = 0; v <= 100;v++){
     if (v % 2 == 0){
    System.out.println(" " + v);        
      }
   }
```

Or put `v = v + 1` outside of if condition:

```
 for (int v = 0; v <= 100;){
    if (v % 2 == 0){
    System.out.println(" " + v);        
   }
   v = v + 1;
 }
```

Comment: I added that in and it continues to print 0's.

Answer (score 0):

Put increment in for and remove it from inside the if statement.

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
for (int v = 0; v <= 100;){
            if (v % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println(" " + v);
            }
            v = v + 1;
        }
```